# Changing Chloropleth Maps based on input in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using ggplot to plot chloropleth maps of the UK based on investment from US to UK. This can be catagorised by either 'Projects', 'Avg Capex' or 'Jobs'. I want to fill the map with colour depending on which of the 3 previous variables is selected.

At the moment my app is only displaying a uniform colour regardless of which option I press. The code works when not in shiny but I can't get it to work in shiny!

My code for the UI and server

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("North America Investment 2019"),
  selectInput(inputId = "group_select", label = "Investment Measure", 
              choices = colnames(together)[c(8,10,11)], selected = colnames(together)[8]),
  plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  g <- ggplot(together, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), col = "black") +
    geom_polygon(aes(fill = input$group_select))
  output$plot <-  renderPlot(g)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

where my colnames(togther) are

```
 [1] "long"         "lat"          "order"        "hole"         "piece"       
 [6] "group"        "id"           "Projects"     "Capex"        "Avg capex"   
[11] "Jobs created" "Avg jobs"     "Companies"
```

This is my first time using RShiny

Comment: Welcome to SO and Shiny! Does using `geom_polygon(aes_(fill = as.name(input$group_select)))` work?

Comment: Hi Nate: No I am getting the following error: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Comment: @regraded0101 try to put the code provided by Nate in ```renderPlot```